# Laravel Sanctum For making Api

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I am testing Laravel Api and using Sanctum for token and i followed the documentation for sanctum but when i used the Route as

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function () { 
    return User::all();
});
```

I am getting the message as

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

in postman . Also , i am passing the token in Authetication in postman (Bearer token).

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot you can see that there is no cookie being sent via postman, can you share your .env value related to sanctum only?

Comment: Sorry,  the problem is solved now